# Number of ways to write a finite set of cardinality n as the union of r distinct binary subsets

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I want to know the number of ways to write a finite set of cardinality $n$ as the union of  $r$ distinct two-element subsets. Is there a nice formula in binomial coefficients?

Comment: Distinct or disjoint?

Comment: distinct, allow to have a common element. Thx

Comment: I believe these numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A054548. Also, https://oeis.org/A276639 is the same tabulation but without the zeros.

Answer (score 3):

My first answer overlooked the fact that you are interested in unions of *two-element* subsets. But in fact the same technique can easily be adapted to this case as well.

We can use Möbius inversion on the Boolean lattice (a.k.a. the principle of inclusion-exclusion) to give a kind of formula, with a sum and with signs.

Let $B_n$ denote the Boolean lattice of subsets of $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. For any $S \in B_n$ let
$$ f(S,r) = \#\{ \{S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_r\colon \#S_i=2\,\forall i\} \subseteq B_n \colon S_1 \cup \cdots \cup S_r = S\}.$$
We are interested in $f([n],r)$.

For any $S\in B_n$ let
$$ g(S,r) = \#\{ \{S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_r\colon \#S_i=2\, \forall i\} \subseteq B_n \colon S_1 \cup \cdots \cup S_r \subseteq S\}= \sum_{T \subseteq S} f(T,r). $$
The key thing to observe is that
$$g(S,r)=  \#\{ \{S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_r\colon \#S_i=2\, \forall i\} \subseteq B_n \colon S_1, \cdots, S_r \subseteq S\} = \binom{\binom{\#S}{2}}{r}.$$

So by Möbius inversion on $B_n$ we get
$$ f([n],r) = \sum_{S \subseteq [n]} \mu_{B_n}(S,[n])g(S,r) = \sum_{S\in B_n} (-1)^{n-\#S}\binom{\binom{\#S}{2}}{r}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{\binom{k}{2}}{r}.$$

Large prime factors appear in these numbers (e.g. $n=9$, $r=8$ gives $9078165$ which has a prime factor of $3011$) so it's unlikely that any formula better than a sum is possible.

---

As a postscript, note that the number you are asking about is the same as the number of graphs on $n$ (labeled) vertices with $r$ edges that have no isolated vertices. Let $f(n,r)$ be this number. Then basic generating function arguments imply
$$ \sum_{n,r \geq 0} f(n,r) \frac{x^n}{n!} y^r = e^{-x} \cdot \sum_{n \geq 0} (1+y)^{\binom{n}{2}}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
From this one can extract the same PIE formula for $f(n,r)$ as above.

---

As Gerry Myerson notes in a comment above, this this triangle of numbers is in the OEIS at https://oeis.org/A054548. However, the only formulas that appear there are the same as the ones given above.

Comment: I am sorry. But  I am interested in subsets of containg exact two elements. Is your Boolen lattice the set of all subsets?

Comment: Ahhh, this is what you meant by "binary subsets." Sorry, I didn't understand that. Okay, I will delete my answer then.

Comment: @liu_c_6 I have now updated the answer to address two-element subset issue.